# Compare two lists with Prolog and collect the different elements in a different list

Tags: prolog

I'm new in Prolog programming language and I'm trying to learn the list structure. I want to compare list A to list B and find all the elements in the A list that are not in the B list and write to List C. Thanks.

Example Query

`match([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],[a,b,c],L3)`

Expected

```
L3=[d,e,f,g]
```

I was able to compare two lists and find "true" as "false". With this code.

```
match([Head|Tail], List2):-
    memberchk(Head,List2).
match([_|Tail],List2):-
    match(Tail,List2).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are two ways. The first one is to write your own predicate:

```
my_subtract([],_,[]):- !.
my_subtract([H|T],B,[H|T1]):-
    \+member(H,B), !,
    my_subtract(T,B,T1).
my_subtract([H|T],B,[H1|T1]):-
    member(H,B), !,
    my_subtract(T,B,[H1|T1]).

test:-
    LA = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g],
    LB = [a,b,c],
    my_subtract(LA,LB,LO1),    
    writeln(LO1).

?- test.
[d, e, f, g]
```

Otherwise you can use in SWI-Prolog the predicate `subtract/3`.

```
test:-
    LA = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g],
    LB = [a,b,c],
    subtract(LA, LB, LO),    
    writeln(LO).

?- test.
[d, e, f, g]
```